# How do I avoid Stack Overflow with circular references in Backbone.js?

Tags: callback, backbone.js, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, silent

Two attributes in my model are supposed to update each other when changed, once. The `startDate` and `endDate`. Their values are Moment objects, from the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

Two Moment objects of identical dates are not equivalent, and so this causes an loop that exceeds the maximum stack, because they appear to Backbone to have always changed.

`new moment('01/01/12') == new moment('01/01/12') // => false`

The `{ silent: true }` option seems not to help, I think because it [only defers the change event](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/398) rather than suppressing it alltogether, though I'm not sure.

**Here's the code that overflows:**

```
class Paydirt.Models.BlockBrowser extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: =>
    @on('change:startDate', @updateEndDate)
    @on('change:endDate', @updateStartDate)
  
  updateStartDate: =>
    @set({ startDate: @cloneEndDate().subtract('days', @get('interval')) }, { silent: true }         

  updateEndDate: =>
    @set({ endDate: @cloneStartDate().add('days', @get('interval')) }, { silent: true } ) 

  cloneStartDate: => new moment(@get('startDate'))
  cloneEndDate: => new moment(@get('endDate'))
```

**I can set a global flag to prevent the callback loop as in this variation:**

```
  updateStartDate: =>
    if !@changing
      @changing = true
      @set({ startDate: @cloneEndDate().subtract('days', @get('interval')) }, { silent: true } ) 
      @changing = false
        
  updateEndDate: =>
    if !@changing
      @changing = true
      @set({ endDate: @cloneStartDate().add('days', @get('interval')) }, { silent: true } ) 
      @changing = false
```

... but this is obviously a hackety solution. Is there a better pattern for me to follow in this use case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea:

Are you using Backbone **v0.9.2**? it looks like it is doing a more intensive use of the `options.silent`. [Look here](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L290-314).

The `options.silent` behavior you're describing looks more like v0.9.1.

Comment: So Backbone v0.9.2 _silent behavior_ is fixing your issue?

Comment: v0.9.2 does prevent the looping behaviour. As it happens, we also implemented some custom events in the full implementation (the code in the OP is demonstrative only), so your advice was excellent all round.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Overwrite the Underscore method `_.isEqual` to manage properly your `Moment` objects. You can use the [Proxy pattern](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Proxy_Pattern).
2. Use [custom events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events) to have more control that when they are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in backbone, but you can compare the integer value of the moments

```
(moment().valueOf() === moment().valueOf()) // true
```

or

```
(+moment() === +moment) // true
```